# dynamodb timestamp reserved name expression-attribute-name

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDb table structure:

```
Primary key: userId, Sort key: timestamp
```

I created this query:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name QAClusteredData \
    --key-condition-expression 'userId= :user_id AND timestamp BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{
        ":user_id": {"S": "ec2e598f-cff8-4648-a120-3baf18e5102c"}, 
        ":t1": {"S": "1550481826"}, 
        ":t2": {"S": "1550662412"}
    }' \
    --region us-east-1
```

received: `"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: timestamp"`

tried:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name QAClusteredData \
    --key-condition-expression 'userId= :user_id AND timestamp BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2' \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#ts":"timestamp"}' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{
        ":user_id": {"S": "ec2e598f-cff8-4648-a120-3baf18e5102c"}, 
        ":t1": {"S": "1550481826"}, 
        ":t2": {"S": "1550662412"}
    }' \
    --region us-east-1
```

still get the same error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

My bad,

had to put `#ts BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2` and not `timestamp BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2`

Full query:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name QAClusteredData \
    --key-condition-expression 'userId= :user_id AND #ts BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2' \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#ts":"timestamp"}' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{
        ":user_id": {"S": "ec2e598f-cff8-4648-a120-3baf18e5102c"}, 
        ":t1": {"S": "1550481826"}, 
        ":t2": {"S": "1550662412"}
    }' \
    --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a forbidden keyword: `:user_id AND timestamp BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2'`

`timestamp` is a reserved word in DynamoDB. Here's a list of reserved keywords in DynamoDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

Comment: You can still use reserved words by using --expression-attribute-names

Comment: Thanks, my bad. You're right, it's explained in the documentation: `If you need to write an expression containing an attribute name that conflicts with a DynamoDB reserved word, you can define an expression attribute name to use in the place of the reserved word. For more information, see Expression Attribute Names. `